# Pipe doesn't work after reg query?

Tags: batch-file

i'm trying to check if there is a java installation on the machine with a batch file,and install java if necessary. However, the pipe doesnt work, and i get the reg query's result on the screen. Here is the code:

```
@ECHO OFF
cls

:checkjava
reg query "HKLM\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" | find "ERROR" > NUL
if %errorlevel% == 0 
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reg query "HKLM\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" 2>&1 | find "ERROR" > NUL
```

the error message is printed in error stream so you need to redirect it in the &1.
Here's more info : http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
reg query "HKLM\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" >nul 2>&1 && goto:OK || goto:fail

:OK
echo reg key found
pause
goto:eof

:fail
echo ERROR key not found!
pause
goto:eof
```

Comment: I tried this too, but there is something wrong, command shell closes immediately when executing this one.Any idea why?

Comment: It always goes to fail,whether i have java installed or not.

Answer (score 1):

Error messages are sent to Standard Error and to Standard Output hence you need to redirect Standard Error to Standard Output before running `find` on the output.

```
reg query "HKLM\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" 2>&1 | find "ERROR" > nul
```

Another thing is that reg query itself returns 0 or 1 on success or failure

```
Return Code: (Except for REG COMPARE)
  0 - Successful
  1 - Failed
```

So you may not have to use `find` at all.

```
reg query "HKLM\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment"  > nul 2> nul

if %errorlevel% == 0  goto success
echo "Not found"
goto end
:success
echo "Found"
:end
```

I am just printing Found/Not found - but you can take whatever action you want.

Comment: so how can i use those 0 or 1? sorry i m really new in this :)